# Unity - How can i make my turnbased AI movement move one at a time

Tags: c#

Not sure if I described the problem correctly in the title, but I'm making a turn-based game and have the enemy movement AI finished. The problem I've got stuck on is making each enemy move separately:
Enemy 1: move and attack
Then
Enemy 2: move and attack
and so forth.
I suppose I could do separate scripts but that would just be a mess in the long run. Do any of you know a more straightforward way of doing it using the same script?

I'm kind of new to game dev and this forum so if this is posted in the wrong forum, please tell me where I should post it instead:)

Comment: Seems like you need to have some of Master script to call individual enemy to move one by one. Even with sample code, this question is board to be able to be answered.

Comment: I don't know `Unity`, but you looked at `Unity Jobs` [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html)  ?

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution, use a public static UnityEvent when you put each enemy's logic then call each method of the UnityEvent one by one when it's the enemies turn to play.